# How to use a count function in map in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdio>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
struct cno{
    int sub[5];
};
int main()
{
    int n;
    map<cno,int> s;
    int maxN = -1;
    struct cno k;
    while(scanf("%d",&n) && n){
        for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
            cin>>k.sub[i];
        }
        if(!s.count(k)){   //Error in this line.
            s[k] = 1;
            maxN = max(maxN,1);
        }
        else{
            int m = s[k] + 1;
            s[k] = m;
            maxN = max(maxN,m);
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

In this code while searching for a struct variable k by using count i get this error.

```
‘const cno’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
       { return __x < __y; }
```

How can we use the count function in C++?What values do count function return?

Comment: [Does this help](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count)?

Answer (score 3):

A `std::map` requires that it's key type implements [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering). In plain language, you have to have the ability to compare keys using the `<` operator.

```
struct cno a, b;

if (a < b)
  // ...
```

This will not compile because you do not have the `<` operator defined on your key type.

You have two options:

1) Implement `operator<` for your custom key class.

2) Pass the third optional parameter to the `std::map` template, specifying a custom comparator class.

Answer (score 3):

In order for `map<K, V>` to work, there must be an `operator <` that can compare two objects of type `K`. This is necessary because a `map` is ordered by its keys. You can, alternatively, supply a comparator type to your map

```
map<K, V, Cmp>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer Armen. Can you explain how can i write the comparator function. i need to sort the elements in an ascending order of the struct variable.